# How to differentiate between intent passed from an onclicklistener of a cardview child to OnActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, onactivityresult

I tried many approaches after reading multiple pages on stackoverflow but I can't seem to get it working.

I have a cardview with onclicklistener to each child clicked (using `setSingleEvent`).

One of the child uses a barcode scanner then passes the scanned barcode to another activity (via `onActivityResult`).

But now I need another child (cardview) to use the same barcode scanner and pass the value to another activity as well. I don't know how to differentiate both clicks in the `onActivityResult` method.

However, the code works fine for a single child grid implementing the barcode scanner `(finali == 0)`. But, in case `(finali == 3)`, how do I pass to the `onActivityResult` a different thing to do?

```
private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //Loop all child item of main Grid
    for (int i = 0;i<mainGrid.getChildCount();i++){
        CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);

          final int finali=i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (finali == 0){
                    Intent intent = BarcodeReaderActivity.getLaunchIntent(getApplicationContext(), true,false);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);

                }
                else if (finali == 1){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AllActiveCheckInActivity.class));
                }
                else if (finali == 2){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Reports Clicked");

                }
                else if (finali == 3){

                    Intent intent = BarcodeReaderActivity.getLaunchIntent(getApplicationContext(), true,false);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my `onActivityResult` that works fine when I make use of only one of the child cardview to implement the barcode scanner.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error in  scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST && data != null) {
            Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeReaderActivity.KEY_CAPTURED_BARCODE);
            String terminal_id = barcode.rawValue;
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,LocationDetails.class);
            intent1.putExtra("terminal_id",terminal_id);
            startActivity(intent1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a different constant as requestCode when calling `startActivityForResult` instead of passing the same one (`BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST`) to each call:

```
if (finali == 0) {
    Intent intent = BarcodeReaderActivity.getLaunchIntent(getApplicationContext(), true,false);
    startActivityForResult(intent, BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_FINALI_1);
}
// ... the remaining code of finali == 1 & finali == 2
else if (finali == 3) {
    Intent intent = BarcodeReaderActivity.getLaunchIntent(getApplicationContext(), true,false);
    startActivityForResult(intent,BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_FINALI_3);
}
```

And then check the requestCode in the onActivityResult method:

```
if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_FINALI_1 && data != null) {
   // Code for finali == 1
} else if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_FINALI_3 && data != null) {
   // Code for finali == 3
}
```